# Hadoop: How job is send to master and to nodes on mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop map reduce basic principles and I can't understand many things. One thing how job is being send from client to master and nodes.

Lets suppose we have client, master server, and two slave server. As I understood Mapper class is on client in java class. Client connects to master and what next? How code in Mapper class is passed to master and after that to nodes? Or I understand everything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the picture, here is what happens:

- You run the job on client by using `hadoop jar` command in which you pass jar file name, class name and other parameters such as input and output
- Client will get new application id and then it will copy the jar file and other job resources to HDFS with high replication factor (by default 10 on large clusters)
- Then Client will actually submit the application through resource manager
- Resource manager keeps track of cluster utilization and submit application master (which co-ordinates the job execution)
- Application master will talk to namenode and determine where the blocks for input are located and then work with nodemanagers to submit the tasks (in the form of containers)
- Containers are nothing but JVMs and they run map and reduce tasks (mapper and reducer classes), when the JVM is bootstrapped job resources that are on HDFS will be copied to the JVM. For mappers these JVMs will be created on same nodes on which data exists. Once the processing is started the jar file will be executed to process the data locally on that machine (typical).

[image: Anatomy of map reduce job using YARN]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Let me show the red thread, correct me please if I am wrong. The jar file is copied to every data node and the code in this jar is executed on every data node. Right?

Comment: Let us say, you have 100 node cluster - first jar file will be copied to 10 different data nodes randomly by default. Then when the tasks are being executing, that task will copy it into jvm either from it self (if available) or from the closest node. You can change the default settings to copy job resources to more than 10 nodes or reduce it.

Comment: And finally jvm instance of every one of 100 node will execute that code. Right?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju Thanks for the nice explanation. I am relatively new to hadoop. May be I am being silly here, but my question is - why does it have to copy the jar file on demand after job submission? What goes wrong if the jar file is pre-installed in HDFS (on multiple data nodes)? Also, is the jar file deleted from the data nodes after the job finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a cluster of 1000 nodes and we have 50 gb of file which is to be processed, suppose we  take block size as 64mb the number of input split will be 50*1024/64 ,so the number of blocks occupied will be 800 and suppose the 800 blocks will have the data which is stored in 300 data nodes,so if you will send your jar to all nodes in the cluster it will be useless because we need our jar only in 300 data nodes.